# How Mock CosmosClient?

Tags: mocking, azure-cosmosdb, xunit

I have the next class that I need to create a xunit test, but I don't know how mock the cosmosclient constructor.

```
public class CosmosDb : ICosmosDb
    {
        private readonly CosmosClient _client;
        private readonly CosmosConfig _cosmosConfig;
        private readonly Container _container;
        private readonly ILogger<ICosmosDb> _logger; 

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cosmosConfig"></param>
        public CosmosDb(ILogger<ICosmosDb> logger,IOptions<CosmosConfig> cosmosConfig)
        {
            _logger = logger;
           _cosmosConfig = cosmosConfig.Value;
            _client = new CosmosClient(_cosmosConfig.ConnectionString);
            _container = _client.GetContainer(_cosmosConfig.Database, _cosmosConfig.ContainerId);
        }


        /// <summary>Creates a document in the database.</summary>
        public async Task CreateItemAsync(Item doc)
        {
            try
            {
                await this.RetryUntilNot429Async(async () => await _container.CreateItemAsync<JObject>(JObject.FromObject(doc)));
            }
            catch (CosmosException cosmosException)
            {
                _logger.LogError(cosmosException,$"Exception while {nameof(CreateItemAsync)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retries the specified method indefinitely until no longer getting a
        /// 429 "Too Many Requests" exception after waiting the recommended
        /// delay.
        /// </summary>
        private async Task<T> RetryUntilNot429Async<T>(Func<Task<T>> method)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    return await method();
                }
                catch (CosmosException dce)
                when (dce.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)dce.RetryAfter.Value.TotalMilliseconds);
                }
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                when ((ae.InnerException is CosmosException dce) && (dce.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429))
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)dce.RetryAfter.Value.TotalMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when create a xunit test and try to create one using the cosmosclient constructor, it demand a valid url in connection string, and when put one, of course cointainer say don't exist , **so how can I mock it??**  `

```
 public class CosmosDbTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateItemAsync_RetrysOn429Error()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockContainer = new Mock<Container>();
            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<CosmosDb>>();
            var mockConfig = new Mock<IOptions<CosmosConfig>>();
            var mockCliente = new Mock<CosmosClient>();

            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.Value.ContainerId).Returns("containerid");
            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.Value.Database).Returns("database");
            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.Value.ConnectionString).Returns("conectionstring");

            var item = new Item { Id = "123", Action = "update", BatchId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
            var itemJObject = JObject.FromObject(item);
            var statusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests;
            var cosmosException = new CosmosException("429 Too Many Requests", statusCode, 0, "0", 0);

            mockCliente.Setup(x => x.GetContainer(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockContainer.Object);
            mockContainer.Setup(x => x.CreateItemAsync<JObject>(itemJObject, null, null, default)).ThrowsAsync(cosmosException);
            

            var cosmosDB = new CosmosDb(mockLogger.Object, mockConfig.Object);


            // Act
            await cosmosDB.CreateItemAsync(item);

            // Assert
            mockContainer.Verify(x => x.CreateItemAsync<JObject>(itemJObject, null, null, default), Times.Exactly(2));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when `RetryUntilNot429Async` is accessible within your test project it is way easier to test the behavior of that method without needing to mock the whole cosmos db stuff.

That said, inject the `CosmosClient`! Do not create it manually like you do currently as you can now not inject a mocked CosmosClient. To be able to inject it you can register the `CosmosClient` as a Singleton.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
                string endpoint = configuration["EndPointUrl"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Please specify a valid endpoint in the appSettings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");
                }

                string authKey = configuration["AuthorizationKey"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authKey) || string.Equals(authKey, "Super secret key"))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Please specify a valid AuthorizationKey in the appSettings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");
                }

                CosmosClientBuilder configurationBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(endpoint, authKey);
                return configurationBuilder
                        .Build();
            });
```

([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions/Startup.cs))

Your code can use the injected instance:

```cs
        public CosmosDb(ILogger<ICosmosDb> logger,CosmosClient client)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _cosmosConfig = cosmosConfig.Value;
            _client = client;
            _container = _client.GetContainer(_cosmosConfig.Database, _cosmosConfig.ContainerId);
        }
```

Then use the parameterless constructor for mocking, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet-preview#azure-cosmos-cosmosclient-ctor)